# create plots based on check box selection in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, visualization

How to create dynamic plots based on checkbox inputs, number of plots should be increased and decreased with respect to the names selected checkbox.

Comment: Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and edit your post according it. Now this question is too broad.

Comment: Please provide the code sniping to provide you the answer

Comment: The above provided link is related to R and i'm looking for suggestions for R shiny. Can you provide any similar topics related to R shiny ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `library(gridExtra)` and plot several plots depends (`grid.arrange`) on how many checkbox you actvated.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("variable", "Variables to show:",
                     c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                       "Transmission" = "am",
                       "Gears" = "gear")),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  require(gridExtra)
  require(ggplot2)

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    if (length(input$variable) == 0) {
      ggplot(data.frame())
    } else {
      gl <- lapply(input$variable, 
                   function(x) ggplot(mtcars, aes(mtcars[, x])) +
                     geom_bar() +
                     xlab(x)) 
      grid.arrange(grobs = gl, nrow = 1)
    }
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```